# smooth switching between the blocks with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have few blocks:

```
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
<div id="d"></div>
....
```

css:

```
#b{display:none;}
#c{display:none;}
#d{display:none;}
....
```

nav:

```
<span id="show-a">Show A Block</span>
<span id="show-b">Show B Block</span>
....
```

How to make, that when i click on `Show A Block` button, div with `id=a` will be shown?

Answer (score 1):

the easiest solution is to have reference to an object:

**html**

```
<span id="show-a" rel="#a">Show A Block</span>
<span id="show-b" rel="#b">Show B Block</span>
```

**js**

```
$('span[rel]').click(function() {
    var obj = $(this).attr('rel');
    $(obj).show();
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mikhailov/mAKZj/

Answer (score 0):

Interchange the Id of span and div. it will work.

css

```
#show-a {display:none;}
```

html

```
<div id="show-a"></div>
<span id="a">Show A Block</span>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('span').click(function() {
        var showId = $(this).attr("id");
        $("#show-" + showId).show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's some of my (more or less random) thoughts:

```
$('span#show-a').click(function() {
    $('div#a').show();
});
```

If you want this to be global (for all ids) you may try something like this:

```
var ids = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', etc.];
for (var i in ids)
{
    var id = ids[i];
    $('span#show-'+id).click(function() {
        $('div#'+id).show();
    });
}
```

Of course you would want to make it more dynamic by somehow getting all ids. The best way is to have all your divs be wrapped in another div with id say `wrapper` and use:

```
var ids = [];
$('div#wrapper div').each(function() {
    ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

If you want other divs to be hidden after click you may add custom class to all divs, say `myClass` and add the following line at the begining of `click` handler:

```
$('div.myClass').hide();
```